# Kafka – check number of messages in each partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, integration-testing, kafka-consumer-api

I've implemented a round-robin partitioner as follows:

```
public class KafkaRoundRobinPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(KafkaRoundRobinPartitioner.class);

    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public KafkaRoundRobinPartitioner() {}

    @Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
        int partitionsCount = partitions.size();

        int partitionId = counter.incrementAndGet() % partitionsCount;
        if (counter.get() > 65536) {
            counter.set(partitionId);
        }
        return partitionId;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {
    }
}
```

Now I want to test that each partition has the same number of messages. For example, if I have 1 topic with 32 partitions and I send 32 messages to this topic, I expect that each partition will have exactly 1 message.

I want to do something like the following:

```
KafkaPartitions allPartitions = new KafkaTopic("topic_name");
for (KafkaPartition partition : allPartitions) {
    int msgCount = partition.getMessagesCount();
    // do asserts
}
```

As far as I know Kafka Java API doesn't provide us with such functionality, but I may have lost something in documentation.

Is there any way to implement it gracefully?

**Update**
I found just a basic solution. Since I'm using a multy-consumer model, I can just do the following for each consumer:

```
consumer.assignment().size();
```

After that I can do:

```
consumer.poll(100);
```

And check that each consumer has a message. And in this case I shouldn't face a situation when one consumer got messages for another from it's partition, because since I have the equal number of consumers and partitions, Kafka should distribute partitions between consumers in a round-robin manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I wrote something like the following.

My KafkaConsumer's worker has the following code:

```
public void run() {
    while (keepProcessing) {
        try {
            ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
            for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
                // do processing
                consumer.commitSync();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Couldn't process message", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my tests I decided to check that **each** consumer did exactly one commit, which means that the messages distribution is in a round-robin manner. The test code:

```
public class KafkaIntegrationTest {

private int consumersAndPartitionsNumber;
private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(consumersAndPartitionsNumber);

@Test
public void testPartitions() throws Exception {
    consumersAndPartitionsNumber = Config.getConsumerThreadAmount(); // it's 5
    KafkaMessageQueue kafkaMessageQueue = new KafkaMessageQueue(); // just a class with Producer configuration
    String groupId = Config.getGroupId();
    List<KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]>> consumers = new ArrayList<>(consumersAndPartitionsNumber);

    for (int i = 0; i < consumersAndPartitionsNumber; i++) {
        consumers.add(spy(new KafkaConsumer<>(KafkaManager.createKafkaConsumerConfig(groupId))));
    }

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(consumersAndPartitionsNumber);
    for (KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer : consumers) {
        executor.submit(new TestKafkaWorker(consumer));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < consumersAndPartitionsNumber; i++) {
        // send messages to topic
        kafkaMessageQueue.send(new PostMessage("pageid", "channel", "token", "POST", null, "{}"));
    }

    latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for (KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer : consumers) {
        verify(consumer).commitSync();
    }
}

class TestKafkaWorker implements Runnable {

    private final KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;
    private boolean keepProcessing = true;

    TestKafkaWorker(KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(Config.getTaskProcessingTopic()));
    }

    public void run() {
        while (keepProcessing) {
            try {
                ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
                    consumer.commitSync();
                    keepProcessing = false;
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seekToBeginning()` and `seekToEnd()` and compute the difference of the offsets you get for each partition.